# MSIE window.open not opening

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

So I'm having a popup that opens upon click on a link, but IE (8.0) doesnt want to show it.

```
<a href="javascript:tellafriend('tellafriend.php?id=<?php echo $obj_id; ?>');">Send page</a>
```

And this function in JS:

```
  function tellafriend(url) {
    popup = window.open(url, "Send page", "width=500,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
    popup.focus();
  }
```

IE tells me the error is at the line `popup = window.open...`

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: And what's the error? I assume the URL in the line `popup =` should read `url`, not `test`. And don't use the `javascript:` protocol on `href`; just provide a valid link and attach the JS using an `onclick` event, attached unobtrusively in a separate JS file. That way, your site won't break when JS is not available.

Comment: Ah sorry, the `test` was in from a test (d'uh) I wrote earlier, of course it reads `url`. The error says nothing, he just points to that line and says `invalid argument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why this happens, but IE doesn't let you have a space in the second parameter of `window.open`. If you change it to

```
popup = window.open(url, "Sendpage", "width=500,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
```

the window will pop up.

Comment: FYI, `send-page` also doesn't work. Seems like it only opens when alphanumerics are set... That's why IE should be banned -.-"